# Smooth the movement of a track bar updated on `onTimeUpdate`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic component containing a video and a custom progress bar and the video tag. Stripped down, it looks like this:

```
export default class Player extends Component {
  state = {
    position: 0,
    duration: 0,
  };

  onDurationChange = ({ target: { duration } }) => this.setState({ duration });

  onTimeUpdate = ({ target: { currentTime: position } }) => this.setState({ position });

  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;
    const { position, duration } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <ProgressBar progress={position / duration} />
        <video
          src={src}
          onTimeUpdate={this.onTimeUpdate}
          onDurationChange={this.onDurationChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I am running into a problem where the time update is running at somewhat "inconsistent" intervals. I hooked into `componentDidUpdate` and recorded the following interval:

[image]

This makes `transition: width 1s linear;` not quite look right. However, I would really like to smooth out the movement of this progress bar. What is the recommended way to do this in react?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) for the animation, taken from my [react-jPlayer](https://github.com/MartinDawson/react-jPlayer/blob/master/src/components/playBar/playBar.jsx) library.

This presumes that progress is going to be used for the `width` style of your div in `<Progress />`.

```
const currentProgressAbsolute = (position, duration) => 100 * (position / duration);

<Motion style={{ smoothProgress: spring(currentProgressAbsolute , [250]) }}>
  {values => <ProgressBar progress={values.smoothProgress} /> }
</Motion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could record the previous time and then when ontimeupdate happens calculate the time difference of currentTime - previous time. Then you can use this to update a CSS transition.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("my-video");
var previousTime = 0;
vid.ontimeupdate = function(){
    timeGap = vid.currentTime - previousTime;
    previousTime = vid.currentTime;
    var percentage = ( vid.currentTime / vid.duration ) * 100;
    document.getElementById("current").style.transition = "left "+timeGap+"s linear 0s";
    document.getElementById("current").style.left = percentage+"%";
};
```